# Voltage level translation

Tags: voltage, level-shifting, digital-communications

I am working on a Vehicle Tracker project. I have few digital inputs coming from vehicle system & their voltage level is 90V. These should go to Micro controller GPIOs which are @ 3.3V. What are the ways to connect these??

Comment: Do you mean you have a few digital "outputs"? Also, what have you uncovered for your options on interfacing so far?

Comment: Yes Andy, they are outputs of Vehicle system. For eg :- Accessories output which will tell the MCU whether Accessories are  on/off. I could not find anything yet. Thats what is worrying!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I'd consider:-

Opto isolation is probably good because it level translates and isolates all in one go. The down side is that they can be slow and possibly working at a few hundred kHz is the top limit.

Resistor potential dividers are the basic method for reducing one digital logic signal to a lower value. However they don't provide isolation and, on a vehicle, this may be required.

Comment: Yes. As I am searching , I could find opto-isolation as safe solution. Can you point me to to some device for a way ahead.

Comment: Here's a very cheap one with kV isolation: http://www.rapidonline.com/electronic-components/isocom-4n25-transistor-optoisolator-20-ctr-58-0810 you can get quad packaged types too. You can get ones with darlington output transistors also.

Comment: Thank you Andy, I tried 4N25 & simulated & it is working. You are a life saver. Thank you.